# python: Find two elements in array that multiply to 20

Tags: python

I have an array of elements and I want to find two elements inside it that multiply to 20.  I need help solving this using hash tables.  The expected output for test_array should output, 4 and 5, with a product of 20.   Thank You

```
test_array = [2,4,1,6,5,40]

counts = {}

for element in test_array:
    if 20 % element == 0 
        counts[element] = 20/element
    else:
        None
print counts
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  I see no attempt to implement a hash table for this exercise.

Comment: What is `else: None` supposed to mean? If you don't need to do anything when the test fails, just leave out the `else:` block entirely.

Comment: Please note that you have a list, not an array; Python does not have a built-in *array* type, although `numpy` has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the result of the division the key of the dictionary, not the current element of the list.

```
for element in test_array:
    if 20 % element == 0:
        counts[20/element] = element
for element in test_array:
    if element in counts:
        print("%d * %d" % (element, counts[element]))
        break
else:
    print "No pair found"
```

Comment: thanks @barmar, below the second "if", rewrite to "print (element, counts[element]) ", you cannot combine an int

Answer (score 1):

If you want all elements and multipliers

```
>>> dict((element, multiplier) for element in test_array for multiplier in test_array if element * multiplier == 20)
{4: 5, 5: 4}
```

There are other slight modifications you could do, but this seems to meet the requirements of your question if I understand it correctly...

if you literally just want 4 and 5 because those two elements both multiply to 20 you can

```
[element for element in test_array for multiplier in test_array if element * multiplier == 20]
>>> [4, 5]
```

if your test array varies and you want a key value pair,  but potentially don't want duplicates you can do a little more work to check

```
for e in test_array:
    for m in test_array:
        if e * m == 20:
            if e in counts.values() and m in counts.keys():
                continue
            counts[e] = m

print(counts)
>>> {4: 5}
```

I strongly sugguest that you break apart the comprehensions and put print statements in if you want to see what's going on.  Thanks

if you want to use modulo and division, you can remove the extra for loop:

```
for element in test_array:
    if 20 % element == 0 and int(20/element) in test_array:
        if int(20/element) in counts.values() and element in counts.keys():
            continue
        counts[int(20/element)] = element

print(counts)
```

And if you want to print everything nicely:

```
for k, v in counts.items(): print("%s * %s = 20" % (k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{tuple(sorted((x, 20//x))) for x in test_array \
    if 20 % x == 0 and 20//x in test_array}

# {(4, 5)}
```